# How to separate data val with a comma

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have created a `select2` field that changes an `input` field's value to the selected options.

I get it to shop correctly when I select it but the selected are not separated by a comma need help please

```js
$(function() {
  // turn the element to select2 select style
  $('.select2').select2({
    placeholder: "Select a state",
    maximumSelectionLength: 2,
    tokenSeparators: [',', ' ', ';'],
    allowClear: true,
  }).on('change', function(e) {      
    var data = $(".select2 option:selected").text();
    $("#test").val(data + ',');
    
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<p>
  <select class="select2" style="width:300px" multiple>
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
    <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
    <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
  </select>
</p>

<input type="text" id="test">
```

see example https://jsfiddle.net/eszv1c47/

Comment: @freedomn-m, that data + "," is for the end of the value not for in between, I have tried to add .join(',') but that does not work

Comment: No worries, you need to get the `.text()` out as an array to use `.join(",")` - answer provided below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to comma separate the values (with `.join(",")` you need to get the option texts as an array.

One option is to use jquery's [`.map()`](https://api.jquery.com/map/#map-callback) to loop through each selected option and return its text in an array.

With no other changes, your code

```
    var data = $(".select2 option:selected").text();
    $("#test").val(data + ',');
```

should be

```
    var data = $(".select2 option:selected").map((i,e) => $(e).text().trim()).toArray();
    $("#test").val(data.join(','));
```

Updated fiddle (with select2 fixed) https://jsfiddle.net/u7zevh3g/

```js
$(function() {
  // turn the element to select2 select style
  $('.select2').select2({
    placeholder: "Select a state",
    maximumSelectionLength: 2,
    tokenSeparators: [',', ' ', ';'],
    allowClear: true,
  }).on('change', function(e) {
    var data = $(".select2 option:selected").map((i,e) => $(e).text()).toArray();
    $("#test").val(data.join(','));
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<p>
    <select  class="select2" style="width:300px" multiple>
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
        <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
        <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
    </select>
</p>

<input type="text" id="test">
```